# Return 0 when there is no row returned

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query which returns Null, to show 0 i can use ISNULL on outer query around CAST, i don't know if it is better to use ISNULL in the inner query.

I have tried using ISNULL with inner query but it returns no rows instead of showing 0. I have tried removing group by clause but still same results.

```
SELECT CAST((SUM(q.AssingWithPO * 1.0) / SUM(q.TotalAssign * 1.0)) * 100
                                                                 AS NUMERIC (10,2))
FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.AssignmentID) AS TotalAssign
    ,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a2.AssignmentID)FROM Assignments a2
       WHERE a2.PODeliveryDate <> '19001212'
        AND a2.AssignmentID = a.AssignmentID ) AS AssingWithPO

  FROM Assignments a
  WHERE a.StaffID = 59
  AND (a.CreatedDate BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20141231')
  GROUP BY a.AssignmentID
)q;
```

**ADDED**

I have simplified this query, thanks to @Gordon

```
SELECT SUM(case when a.PODeliveryDate <> '19001212' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / COUNT(*)) * 100 as AssignWithPO
 FROM Assignments a
 WHERE a.StaffID = 59 AND
       a.CreatedDate BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20141231';
```

Now would it be okay to use ISNULL like that?

ISNULL((SUM(case when a.PODeliveryDate <> '19001212' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / COUNT(*)) * 100 as AssignWithPO,0)

**Execution Plan of both queries**

[image]

Comment: I think you should do this in your application instead of in your query.

Comment: Which database are you using? Also could you post the SQL where you tried to use `ISNULL`?

Comment: ISNULL( CAST(
   (SUM(q.AssingWithPO * 1.0) / SUM(q.TotalAssign * 1.0)) * 100 
               AS NUMERIC (10,2)) ,0)

Comment: @user1263981 . . . The answer to your final question is that it is fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: you meant using ISNULL fine? ISNULL((SUM(case when a.PODeliveryDate <> '19001212' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / COUNT(*)) * 100 as AssignWithPO,0)

Comment: @user1263981 . . Yes, using `isnull()` is fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Please check the execution plan i just added into my question. Do you think the second one has better performance?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second level of subqueries.  You can use conditional aggregation instead.  I think the following will do what you want:

```
SELECT CAST((SUM(a.AssignWithPO * 1.0) / SUM(a.TotalAssign * 1.0)) * 100 as NUMERIC (10,2))
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalAssign,
             SUM(case when a.PODeliveryDate <> '19001212' then 1 else 0 end) as AssignWithPO
     FROM Assignments a
     WHERE a.StaffID = 59 AND
           a.CreatedDate BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20141231'
     GROUP BY a.AssignmentID
    ) a;
```

I'm not 100% sure, because I don't understand the relationships between `AssignmentId`, `StaffId`, and `CreatedDate`, but my assumption is that the rows counted for `AssignWithPO` are subject to the same conditions as the `TotalCount`.

You don't need the `count(distinct)` because `AssignmentId` is necessarily unique because of the `group by`.  Assuming there is no overlap between the values, you don't need the `group by` either, nor the outer query:

```
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalAssign,
            SUM(case when a.PODeliveryDate <> '19001212' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / COUNT(*) as AssignWithPO
     FROM Assignments a
     WHERE a.StaffID = 59 AND
           a.CreatedDate BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20141231';
```

Comment: thanks for simplyfying the query. I have tested your query but it still reyurns NULL not zero.

Comment: This statement returns NULL.  SUM(case when a.PODeliveryDate <> '19001212' then 1 else 0 end) as AssignWithPO

Comment: That would suggest that no rows are matching the `where` clause.  Are you sure your dates expressions are what you intend?

Comment: user specifies date range so it can be any